Extreme points in the set of central probability measures on a group
Let $G$ be a finite group and $CS(G)$ the set of probability measures that are invariant under the adjoint action, so $\varphi\in CS(G)$ exactly when for all $g,\,t\in G$):
$$\varphi(t^{-1}gt)=\varphi(g).$$
For any normal subgroup $N\lhd G$, the measure $\varphi_N$ uniform on $N$ (and zero off $N$) is in $CS(G)$. The set $CS(G)$ satisfies the conditions of Krein--Milman so has extreme points.

Is it true that the extreme points of $CS(G)$ are precisely the collection of measures $\varphi_N$?


Do I correctly understand the question, assuming that $G$ is compact, measures are Radon, and $N$ is closed?

@Matsmir sorry I was actually going to start with just finite. Let me fix that. My understanding is that if it is true in the finite case it may generalise.

No, the extreme points are the uniform measures on conjugacy classes.

@SeanEberhard that's what ChatGPT said... but then I put this alternative forward and of course it said "oh actually you're right"!!

@SeanEberhard if you wish to make your comment an answer I will accept.

You have correctly discovered that ChatGPT is better at bullshitting than it is at mathematics.

@SeanEberhard discovered this very early!

No, the extreme points are the uniform measures on conjugacy classes.
